# Deleted question in review queue answer test

Tags: support, review-audits

This review of a late answer has no question:
[image]

Okay, it was a test question, supposed to be this one:

https://serverfault.com/questions/656660/show-me-the-reason-behind-http-error-500-0-internal-server-error-in-the-brow

Comment: Just so you know, the answer to that is to vote down or flag.  It was converted to a comment before the OP self-deleted his question.

Comment: Thanks. I had voted "No Action Needed," because how can a disembodied answer require an action?

Comment: I don't think answers to deleted _questions_ should be eligible to become audits...

Comment: Yeah, well, you know... *developers*.